# How to install salesforce content connector amps in alfresco 6.2 docker container

Tags: docker, salesforce, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have installed Alfresco 6.2 using docker and it's vanilla instance is up and running.
Now, I have to install following Salesforce content connector amp files, but I am facing

```
alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-repo-2.1.x.amp

alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-share-2.1.x.amp
```

I tried to copy these files in docker container and tried to install it using following command.

```
java -jar /usr/local/tomcat/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install /usr/local/tomcat/amps /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco -directory -nobackup -force
```

But, I am not able to install same and getting following error.

```
05290000 An IO error was encountered during deployment of the AMP into the WAR
The command '/bin/sh -c java -jar ${TOMCAT_DIR}/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install \ ${TOMCAT_DIR}/amps ${TOMCAT_DIR}/webapps/alfresco --force' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can someone please help me with the correct steps to install these amps if I am doing anything wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the root user to build the docker file.

Docker file for repo amp:

FROM alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:6.2.0-ga

```
USER root

COPY ./amps/alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-repo-2.1.x.amp /usr/local/tomcat/amps/

RUN java -jar /usr/local/tomcat/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install /usr/local/tomcat/amps /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco -directory -nobackup -force \
 && chown -R root:Alfresco /usr/local/tomcat

USER alfresco
```

Docker file for share amp :

```
FROM alfresco/alfresco-share:6.2.0

COPY ./amps/alfresco-content-connector-for-salesforce-share-2.1.x.amp /usr/local/tomcat/amps_share/

RUN java -jar /usr/local/tomcat/alfresco-mmt/alfresco-mmt*.jar install /usr/local/tomcat/amps_share /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/share -directory -nobackup -force \
```

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Connector is for Enterprise only. If you have a licence you should contact support for assistance.
Cheers,

Comment: I am doing this as a POC for our COE LAB and can't go to support for assistance.